# Nextjs useEffect and useState hook not working on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I use the `useEffect` and `useState`-hooks to get some data:

```
export default function PricingBlock({ data }) {
  const [pricingItems, setPricingItems] = useState()
  const [featuredItem, setFeaturedItem] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPricingItems = async () => {
      const pricingItems = await request({ query: PRICING, variables: {} })
      const items = await pricingItems?.allSpecialistPages
      const featured = pricingItems?.specialistLandingpage?.card[0]
      setPricingItems(items)
      setFeaturedItem(featured)
   }
    getPricingItems()
  }, [featuredItem, pricingItems])

 return (
   <div>
     <div
       style={{
         backgroundColor: featuredItem?.backgroundColor?.hex,
         backgroundImage: `url(${featuredItem?.backgroundImage?.url})`,
         borderTop: '1px solid ' + featuredItem?.backgroundColor?.hex,
         borderLeft: '1px solid ' + featuredItem?.backgroundColor?.hex,
         borderRight: '1px solid ' + featuredItem?.backgroundColor?.hex,
       }}
     > ... </div>
   </div>
 )
}
```

when I run this locally, it works fine, but when I run `npm run build`- I get the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` referring to `featuredItem`

I also tried to do:

```
const [featuredItem, setFeaturedItem] = useState({}) - as an object
```

but then I get the error `Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type '{}'.`

How can I solve this? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this will solve it:

```
interface FeaturedItem {
    backgroundColor: string;
    //other props if needed...
}
const [featuredItem, setFeaturedItem] = useState<FeaturedItem>();
```

- without the generic on `useState`, typescript assign featuredItem as undefined

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the TypeScript error. This code:

```
const [featuredItem, setFeaturedItem] = useState()
```

Does not define the type of `featuredItem`, so it does not have the first accessed property (`backgroundColor`).

Either fix it, or in your `next.config.js`, temporarily add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If not using Typescript you could try giving `featuredItem` state a default value.

```js
const defaultValue = {
  backgroundColor: {
    url: '',
    hex: ''
  },
  backgroundImage: ''
};
const [featuredItem, setFeaturedItem] = useState(defaultValue)
```